# Data Atual VBA com mês

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, data

Bom dia,

Tenho um formulário no qual no campo textbox este recebe a data do dia e em que noutro textbox ele extrai o mês da data.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso, hoje é dia 10/02/2022 mas ele assume que é dia 02/10/2022, terá a ver com o modo em inglês? Como posso fazer para ficar com a hora em PT, neste caso 10/02/2022.

O código que estou a usar é o seguinte

`txt_datarececao = Date`

Obrigado desde já pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Para informar que já consegui resolver o problema.

Neste caso criei uma variável e esta assume a data com o formato que desejo.

Fica abaixo caso seja útil para alguém.

```
Dim data As String

data = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
txt_datarececao = data
```